# Repopulate drop downs if user changes their mind on one selection

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-select

Ok, I will try to describe my problem as thoroughly as possible.  I have 2 select boxes.  One is fine.  The other has a list of countries and depending on what country the user selects, HTML generates another drop down(states) that is populated with states regarding that country.  If the country doesnt have a state/province, it just goes to another part of the form (another HTML page). That part (no state/provinces) is working fine. The way I have it set up now, if the user selects United States I get a third drop down that has states in it. Then if the user changes their mind from "United States" to lets say "United Kingdom", I want HTML to generate the the states/provinces for United Kingdom, not United States. Right now, its set up in a way that if they change their mind, it submits the from and the user can only select from schools all over the country they changed their mind to. It skips the state/province part.  I know this may be confusing but if you have any questions feel free to ask.
Here is my HTML and javascript code.  Any help is appreciated. I know I probably shouldn't use the submit method but Im not sure how else to accomplish this.

```
<form id="form" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?S2XEvent=Step1half" method="post">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="50%">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <fieldset class="fs">
            <legend class="blue">General Information</legend>

            <div class="error-msg"><? $this->DisplayValidatorError() ?></div>

            <div id="step_1half">
                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr> 
                        <td class="form-label-required">Affiliation Type: <span class="asterisk">*</span></td>
                        <td><?= $this->GenHTML_Select('affiliation_type', $aff_type, $affiliation_type, 'form-input-stretched'); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                        <td class="form-label-required">Country: <span class="asterisk">*</span></td>
                        <td> 
                            <select  id="country_code" name="country_code" class="form-input-stretched" onchange="refresh()">
                            <? while(list($abbrev, $name) = each($countries)) { ?>
                            <? if($name == 'Common Countries' || $name == 'Alphabetical Listing') { ?>
                            <option value="<?= $abbrev ?>" class="bg"><?= htmlentities( $name ) ?></option>
                            <? } else { ?>        
                            <option <?= ($abbrev == $country_code || ($country_code == '' && trim($abbrev) == 'USA') ) ? 'selected' : '' ?> value="<?= $abbrev ?>"><?= htmlentities( $name ) ?></option>
                            <? } ?>
                            <? } ?> 
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <script>
                        function refresh(){
                            window.getSelection($(this).val(), '');                                 
                            $("#form").submit();
                        }                               
                        </script>
                     <?  if ($total > 0){   ?>                                           
                        <tr> 
                        <td class="form-label-required">State: <span class="asterisk">*</span></td>
                        <td> 
                            <select name="state_province_code" class="form-input-stretched">
                                <?= implode('', $states); ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                        <td class="form-label">City:</td>
                        <td><input name="city" type="text" class="form-input-stretched" id="city" value="<?= $city ?>" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <? } else { echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=https://blahblahblah?S2XEvent=Step2\">";} ?>
                </table>
```

Comment: If you're asking for JavaScript help, post HTML, not PHP.

Comment: This is HTML (with a little PHP). lol

Comment: Fair enough, but it's best practice on SO to eliminate all extraneous code. It makes it easier for us to help. You get out what you put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use JavaScript and a toolkit like jQuery. Grab the original options for the drop down that has to be changed back and save them in some variable. Then when the user changes their mind just reinsert them with jQuery's DOM manipulation API.

Comment: cool thanks.  I'll check it out.  Not too familiar with it though.  I'd give you a vote up but my rep is only 10. Haha

Comment: Ok, Ive looked into the jQuerys DOM manipulation and I still cant get this to work.  Ive searched everywhere for help but nothing pertains to my problem.